# Svelte grid layout with WindiCSS

Tags: grid, svelte, windicss

I have a grid layout set-up with windicss with this code

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 w-auto">
<div class="w-15">
  <img class="h-15" src="https://starnumber.tk/logo.png" alt="logo">
</div>
<div>
  <p class="text-left font-mono"><span class="text-xl">StarNumber12046</span><br>Svelte lover</p>
</div>
```

but the div takes too much space

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That image link is rather dead.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QNcvTtN.png new link

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting the `display` to an `inline-flex` fixes the problem.